# Starting ProFTPD fail

Tags: xampp, proftpd

I have a problem with start ProFTPD.
the command window displays this message when I start ProFTPD.

```
asil@asil-PC:~$ sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
Starting XAMPP for Linux 7.0.9-0...
XAMPP: Starting Apache...already running.
XAMPP: Starting MySQL...ok.
XAMPP: Starting ProFTPD...fail.
XAMPP:  Another FTP daemon is already running
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ProFTPD have to access Port 21 as it is service default port and its clearly saying that some other service using that port already.

you can see what service using that port by using , mostly probably another FTP service like vsftpd etc

```
netstat -peanutl | grep :21
```

you can kill that service and try starting ProFTPD.

else you can change default port to someother port with syntax in configuration file.

```
Port <Port_number>
```

[Read this link](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/howto/ConfigurationTricks.html)

Comment: How I can kill this service to restarting ProFTPD?

Comment: sudo kill - 9 pid